# Is it possible to put files other than index.jsp on SSL using Heroku?

Tags: facebook, ssl, heroku, indexing

I use Heroku to host my Facebook application. The app works fine. The only thing is my app is dependent on two files : namely, index.jsp and result.jsp.

Now, by default the index.jsp file is on secure ssl (https), but when my application redirects the user to result.jsp, it is loaded on http (not on ssl)

Is there any way I can put the other file (ie. result.jsp) on ssl too?

Is there any Git commands for that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually detect whether the user has accessed a non-https url using the `x-forwarded-proto` http request header and then redirect them to the https url.